# Issue using knockout checked binding with radio button

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to use the checked binding but it doesn't seem to work. I have tried the solutions that are mentioned in stackoverflow for similar issue but none have worked.

I am getting the model via jquery ajax. I have the model in the c# code which i am binding  in UI.
I am also saving the data via jquery ajax. Elements that have value data-binding seem to work, but the checked binding with radio button shows null and is not being updated.

```
var LoginInformationModel = function () {
            LoginInformation = ko.observable();
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                type: "GET",
                url: "Login.svc/GetLogin",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    if (msg.Login != undefined) {
                        LoginInformation(msg.Login);
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) { 
                    alert('error:' + xhr.responseText) }
                    //log('error calling Login.svc: ' + xhr.responseText); 
                }
            });
}

ko.applyBindings(LoginInformationModel);
```

Model in C#:

```
public class Login
{
    string namePrefix;
    public string NamePrefix { 
        get { return namePrefix; } 
        set { namePrefix = value; } 
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content" class="container" data-bind="with: LoginInformation()">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="four columns">
            <label>&nbsp;Prefix:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="fourteen columns custom-label">
            <label for="prefixMr">
                <input type="radio" class="input-display-none" 
                       id="prefixMr" name="NamePrefix" value="Mr." 
                       data-bind="checked: NamePrefix"/>
                <span class="custom radio"></span>Mr.
            </label>
            <label for="prefixMrs">
                <input type="radio" class="input-display-none" 
                       id="prefixMrs" name="NamePrefix" value="Mrs." 
                       data-bind="checked: NamePrefix"/>
                <span class="custom radio"></span>Mrs.
            </label>
            <label for="prefixMs">
                <input type="radio" class="input-display-none" 
                       id="prefixMs" name="NamePrefix" value="Ms." 
                       data-bind="checked: NamePrefix"/>
                <span class="custom radio"></span>Ms.
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to zurb foundation that I was using and not with knockout.
I commented out the code for the radio button toggle in the zurb foundation forms and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this fiddle for complete answer     http://jsfiddle.net/32UU6/

There are two issues with your code.
One is the way you are using `with` binding. Update that line to show something like this

```
<div id="content" class="container" data-bind="with: LoginInformation">
```

notice that after `LoginInformation` we do not have `()`.

Second, `NamePrefix` should be an observable, right now it is plain JavaScript value, so two way binding will not work. Fix for this is either you can use `ko.mapping` plugin or simply make it an observable and assign the value to it after AJAX call succeeds.

One more thing, binding with radio buttons will only work if `NamePrefix` has exact same values as we have specified in radio button `value` attribute. So, if radio button value matches with NamePrefix value, then that radio button will be selected.